# app_code files not found by the project

Tags: c#, asp.net

my name is samy and im going insane!

i got this problem that my class's in app_code are no visible afther im uploading them to the server.
localy every thing work fine.

i read some other qustions on this when a lot of answer were like this:

"Right-click on the item in the solution explorer, and select Properties. In the properties window, there is a Build Action option."

```
 *when i right click i cant see any proprty button so i used F4 but then i cant see any build option only "Custom Tool", "File Name" , "Full Path".
```

and 
 "you need to publish your website first."
 *this didnt work either.

or 
 "your class are not compiled.
 *i tried to build solution and that didnt work either.

please help me becuse im starting read/see tutorials on how to make a good rope knots (this will probly fails too so dont worry to much lol)

this is the error im getting (its look like this becuse im using iframe)
http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/11/theerrorb.png

this is error i get if i publish the site and upload it to the server all the app_code files are compiled in the bin folder as you said.

http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/4436/errorifipublish.png

Comment: when you compile, build and publish code app_code folder is compiled into a dll file and not as a folder. Check your bin folder and see if you see that dll on server.

Comment: cant see any dll in my bin other that what i put there. any other idea? what can block me for getting to my class proprties?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Possible Solution 1

I have seen this before when working with ASP.NET Web Sites. If my memory serves me right, you should make sure that the paths to your references are wired up correctly.

i.e. if you added a custom DLL to your project

> C:\My References\Some3rdParty.dll

and you moved the DLL to another folder/location. Or you could simply have a reference to a DLL that cannot be found.

If you resolve these reference problems you could find that your **App_Code** gets compiled all of a sudden.

#### Possible Solution 2

Right click and go to the properties of each of the **.cs** files in your **App_Code** directory in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer and make sure that the **Build Action** is set to **Compile**.

#### Possible Solution 3

If you have your **.cs** files in sub-folders within the **App_Code** directory you should add the following to your web.config file:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation>
         <codeSubDirectories>
           <add directoryName="MySubAppCodeFolderName"/>
         </codeSubDirectories>
      </compilation>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

#### Possible Solution 4

1. In Visual Studio, right-click on your Web Site in the **Solution Explorer** and click **Publish Web Site**. Make sure that the Target Location is a folder on your machine.
2. Log-in you your web-server and go to the BIN folder there. In the BIN folder on your web site delete all of the **App_Web_*.dll*** and **App_Web_.dll.compiled** files.
3. From your machine, copy your web site (including the App_Web_*.dll's in the BIN) to your web server where your web site is located. The only file you should probably **not copy across** is your **Web.config** file.

Comment: @samy If any of these solutions work for you can you let us know for future reference. Thanks

Comment: 1.i got 1 dll file in the bin "Flicker.dll" 2. i cant see any option to get in the class proprties :( 3.i got only 2 .cs file in app_code and thay are not in sub folder. any other idea?

Comment: 1. Have you tried running Visual Studio with administrator privileges? 2. Is this a new Web Site or an old one that has stopped working?
3. Was this working before? Have you made any changes such as changing the .NET framework version etc..?

Comment: 1.i just tried that and cant see any diffrents. 2.is a website i made about 1 month ago but just now add a server side code 3.the site is working localy, but when i upload it to a server some pages who use some of the .cs in the app_code give me errors 4.thank you for your help :)

Comment: No problem, can you edit your original post and put the exact errors that you are getting? You may need to set customErrors off in your Web.config i.e.

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: Another question, when you 'Publish' your Web site, do you have App_web.dll's in your published \Bin\ folder?

Comment: i upload a image of the error im getting. I tried upload a 'Published' version befor to the server and it gave an error too. now im gonna try the web.config thing you suggested.

Comment: @i have this line in the config mybee this is the problem? <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/> should i delete this line and add what you suggested?

Comment: You do not need to delete this line in your Web.config you should set the debug="false" when your site is finished and tested.

Comment: i added a image of the error i get if i upload a "published" version of my website.

Comment: Ok here is what to try. #1. Delete any App_Web.dll and App_Web.dll.compiled's in your web servers \Bin\ folder. You could have a lot of these. #2. In Visual Studio, publish your web site and copy the new files up. It is really important to make sure that all of your App_Web.dll's and App_Web.dll.compiled are deleted from your BIN folder on your web server.

Comment: i tried deleting all the App_Web.dll in my bin folder afther i published the website and upload it to the server and got the parser error.  i didnt understand the second part: do i need to publish the site agian and copy the App_Web.dll files from the new published site to the old published site?

Comment: Ok, what I meant for you to do is 1. In Visual Studio, right-click on your Web Site and click 'Publish Web Site'. Make sure that the Target Location is a folder on your machine. 2. Log-in you your web-server and go to the BIN folder there. In the BIN folder on your web site delete all of the App_Web_*.dll and App_Web_*.dll.compiled files. 3. From your machine, copy your web site (including the App_Web_*.dll's in the BIN) to your web server where your web site is located. I have edited and added 'Possible Solution 4' to my original reply.

Comment: so you mean 1.publish and upload the site as it is 2.then delete all the App_Web_*.dll's and App_Web_*.dll.compiled from the bin folder (On the server) 3.then upload all the App_Web_*dll's to the bin folder(On the server)?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Basically, delete your App_Web dll's in your server's BIN folder and upload the version from your local machine.

Comment: i tried that and that didnt work so i asked another qustion and people told me to change it to a web appliction so im giving you right answer becuse you help ALOT :) thank you for everything!

Comment: No worries, pity we couldn't resolve the web site issue. Any projects I create are Web Applications in work. I have to work with one or two Web Sites and it causes nothing but heartache. Glad it's working. Best of luck